# save data to DB

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql, sql-server-express

I am using Visual Studio 2010 with SQL Server Express and LINQ to SQL

The application runs correctly when inserting data into the database during application execution.  The data is inserted to the database.  But, when I stop the application and click `show table data` in `server explorer` I do not see any data. Why is this so?

Here the values for the copy output direction properties for my database solution items:

```
database1.mdf: copy always
database1Dataset.xsd: do not copy
dataclasses1.dbml: do not copy
```

Comment: @whoever voted to close: This question is poorly worded, but it is definitely a "real question" and the OP obviously does not speak English as a primary language.

Answer (score 2):

> database1.mdf=====> properties =======>copy output direction=copy always

This is why.  You are editing a copy of the database each time you start a new debug session.  Set it to `do not copy` and your updates will persist.

Comment: do not copy:: say this error:An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file F:\test\tdb\tdb\bin\Debug\Database1.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

Comment: @dKL f j sdlf: Looks like you added the data source from the debug directory. Don't do that; add it from its original directory.